# How does this kbd function work?

Tags: kdb

Would someone please explain the below function? How does the kdb utilize x here?

I changed the original function to "func" I know it uses the queries assigned in que to query both functions. The problem is I don't know how those x 0 and and x 0 1 work here. I know 0 is the index 1 and 1 is the index 2 and x is the parameter.

```
svcs:`TEST:1`TEST:2
que: (`$"select count sym from trades";`$"select sum size from trades")

{func[x 0;string x 1],x 0 1}each svcs cross que
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x is being passed in as a two element list "each" time the function is called.

Forget about the func description for now and just add in some logging to see things more clearly:

```
q)svcs cross que
TEST:1 select count sym from trades
TEST:1 select sum size from trades
TEST:2 select count sym from trades
TEST:2 select sum size from trades
q){show enlist "x 0 is ",string x 0;show enlist "x 1 is ",string x 1;show raze "
x 0 1 is ",(string x 0)," & ", (string x 1)}each svcs cross que;
"x 0 is TEST:1"
"x 1 is select count sym from trades"
"x 0 1 is TEST:1 & select count sym from trades"
"x 0 is TEST:1"
"x 1 is select sum size from trades"
"x 0 1 is TEST:1 & select sum size from trades"
"x 0 is TEST:2"
"x 1 is select count sym from trades"
"x 0 1 is TEST:2 & select count sym from trades"
"x 0 is TEST:2"
"x 1 is select sum size from trades"
"x 0 1 is TEST:2 & select sum size from trades"
```

Or an individual example:

```
q)x:(`TEST:1;`$"select count sym from trades")
q)x 0
`TEST:1
q)x 1
`select count sym from trades
q)x 0 1
`TEST:1`select count sym from trades
```

x 0 1 indexes and retrieves both the first and second element (returning

Answer (score 1):

You're right and `x 0` or `x 1` is the same as `x[0]` or `x[1]` (see the link below on indexing lists), except perhaps the problem is that it isn't obvious what `x` is.

Because of the adverb `each` the function is executed *four* times, once for each item in `svcs cross que`

See;

```
q)count svcs cross que
4
```

And then each item in `svcs cross que` has two items.

```
q)count each svcs cross que
2 2 2 2
```

So in the first execution, `x` is the first item of `svcs cross que` and so on.

```
q)first svcs cross que
`TEST:1`select count sym from trades
q)(first svcs cross que) 0
`TEST:1
q)(first svcs cross que) 1
`select count sym from trades
q)(first svcs cross que) 0 1
`TEST:1`select count sym from trades
```

Reference

http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#671-monadic-each

http://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#34-indexing